# Change order of rows in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to transform a matrix:

```
X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
X = 1 2
    3 4
    5 6
    7 8
```

to

```
X = [1 2; 5 6; 3 4; 7 8]
X = 1 2
    5 6
    3 4
    7 8
```

and do this operation for a matrix with any number of rows. So that in a matrix with 200 rows, row 101 will become row 2, row 102 will become row 4 and so on.
How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrays with an even number of rows, you do the following:

```
nRows = size(X,1);

idx = [1:nRows/2;nRows/2+1:nRows];

X_rearranged = X(idx(:),:);
```

For arrays with odd number of rows, you add 1 to `nRows`, and use `idx(1:end-1)` instead of `idx(:)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]
Y = [a(1,:); a(3,:); a(2,:); a(4,:)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but you should probably read the question more thoroughly the next time. This is technically correct for the example OP is using, but he specifies that it should be possible to do this for hundreds of rows. This approach is very impractical for larger cases.